# Which Visual Studio project type to choose for windows 8 app not running in full-screen

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-express

I have an idea for a windows 8 application that I want to develop using VS2012 Express for Windows 8. The application will have a very simple UI and the interaction is minimal. I would like the app to have a kind of "widget" appearance, but I don't know if this can be accomplished with a windows 8 app or I need another type of project. My question is if this can be done in VS2012 Express for Windows 8 with a simple Blank App project type?

Comment: In simple words, it's not possible. Windows Store Apps are meant to run in full screen. Though the filled & snapped states. You can use that.

Comment: Thanks Xyroid, I'll check out the two states and see if I can use those.

Comment: Or you could get VS2012 Express for Desktop and use it to build WPF app.

Comment: I haven't really worked that much with WPF but I guess that's no excuse - if the tool is right then that gives me an excuse to try something new :-)

Comment: To Xyroid and Denis: As an update I had to "kill this darling" and abandon the idea but I also think others could benefit from your comments even though my question in retrospect may be too general. If you don't mind posting your comments as answers I'll leave it up to the community to decide.